# JDBC - select query from a materialized view does not work

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc, nativequery

I'm trying to create a select query from a materialized view using jdbc. Here is my actuall code:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT v.name FROM my_materialized_view v");
List<Object[]> authors = q.getResultList();
```

But when I run this code I get the following error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

There's an specific to select materialized views in this context? Because if I use that code querying from a normal table it works perfect...

Comment: Are you specifically trying to select only the column `name`? (Note that you're using raw types, which is never a good practice, though I don't _think_ it's directly causing the error.)

Comment: no, this is only an example. I need to select more columns. By the way I've tried without the SQL ALIAS and the error still there :x

Comment: If you're selecting multiple columns, in JPA the usual practice is to define a class `ViewRecord` and use it in your query. You can normally even just write it as an `@Entity` and use the standard query mechanisms; the fact that the table providing the data is a view is transparent to Hibernate.

Comment: Maybe I undertand... But, can you write a little example for me please?

Comment: @tc9900 Could you please provide the **full** stacktrace?

Answer (score -1):

dont use SQL ALIAS

try

```
"SELECT name FROM my_materialized_view"
```

Comment: I've tried now without SQL ALIAS but the error still the same...

Comment: The alias is perfectly valid SQL